# Set Color of Chevron in a SwiftUI List in a NavigationView

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have this list I a NavigationView.
In dark mode the Chevron (red circle) is almost invisible.

[image]
How can I set the Color of Chevron in a List.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
      NavigationView{
        List {
          Line(text: "Line 1")
          Line(text: "Line 2")
          Line(text: "Line 3",selected: true)
          Line(text: "Line 4")
          Line(text: "Line 5")
        }
      }
    }
}

struct Line: View {
  var text :String
  var selected = false
  @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

  var body: some View {
    NavigationLink(destination: Text("D")) { Text(text)}
      .listRowBackground(selected ? Color.blue : Color(.systemBackground))
      .foregroundColor(selected ? Color.white : Color(.label))
    .onTapGesture(perform: {print ("tap")
    } )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard chevron is not a symbol by raster image, here it is

[image: demo1]

that is why it does not react on any color changing modifiers.

Solution, disable standard chevron and use own, custom, (behaviour of the List is the same), like below

```
HStack {
    Text(text)
    NavigationLink(destination: Text("D")) { EmptyView() } // disabled  !
    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")                     // << custom !!
        .foregroundColor(Color.red)                        // any color !!!
}
```

[image: demo2]

Comment: And then, when you enter editing mode, the reinvent-the-wheel chevrons remain visible, because why think about all the edge cases that UIKit supports out-of-the-box, right? This is never a good solution.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the "serial voting reversed" indicator anyway. It means somebody previously upvoted many of your answers systematically, and when the system detected this, those votes were removed. Feel free to search [meta] for a fuller discussion.

Answer (score 2):

In my environment, default chevron is shown under customized chevron.

Add opacity(0), it works.

```
NavigationLink(destination: Text("D")) { EmptyView() }
    .opacity(0) // Add this
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `accentColor` property:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
      List {
        Line(text: "Line 1")
        Line(text: "Line 2")
        Line(text: "Line 3",selected: true)
        Line(text: "Line 4")
        Line(text: "Line 5")
      }.accentColor(.black)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on my end. Also `.accentColor` is deprecated: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/ellipse/accentcolor(_:)/